# How to use SQL Server 2005 Pivot based on lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

table [Status] has the following data:

```
ID  Status
1   PaymentPending
2   Pending
3   Paid
4   Cancelled
5   Error
```

====================================

Data Table has the following structure:

```
ID    WeekNumber StatusID
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       1           3
4       2           1
5       2           2
6       2           2
7       2           3
```

Looking for a Pivot

```
Week #      PaymentPending     Pending     Paid    Cancelled
Week 1            1                1         1         0
Week 2            1                2         1         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
       'Week ' + CAST(D.WeekNumber AS varchar(2)) [Week #], 
       S.Status 
    FROM DataTbl D
    INNER JOIN Status S ON D.StatusID = S.ID
    ) Derived
PIVOT 
(
COUNT(Status) FOR Status IN 
  ([PaymentPending], [Pending], [Paid], [Cancelled]) -- add [Error] if needed
) Pvt
```

If you expect the number of items in the`Status`table to change you might want to consider using a dynamic pivot to generate the column headings. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Status)
FROM (SELECT ID, Status FROM Status) AS Statuses ORDER BY ID

SET @sql =
  N'SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT ''Week '' + CAST(D.WeekNumber AS varchar(2)) [Week #], S.Status
    FROM Datatbl D
    INNER JOIN Status S ON D.StatusID = S.ID) Q
    PIVOT (
       COUNT(Status)
          FOR Status IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS Pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45d36/4)

Comment: While the other solutions are also valid, this solution with the dynamic sql provides the best solution for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Week '+CAST(coun.WeekNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) [Week #],[PaymentPending],[Pending],[Paid],[Cancelled],[Error] FROM 
(SELECT [WeekNumber],[Status] FROM dbo.WeekDetails 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Status] AS s
ON [dbo].[WeekDetails].[StatusID] = [s].[ID]) AS wee
PIVOT (COUNT(wee.[Status]) FOR wee.[Status]
IN  ([PaymentPending],[Pending],[Paid],[Cancelled],[Error])) AS Coun
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE based aggregation with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 'Week ' + cast(WeekNumber as varchar(10)) as 'Week#',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN StatusId =1 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'PaymentPending',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN StatusId =2 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'Pending',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN StatusId =3 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'Paid',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN StatusId =4 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'Cancelled'
FROM DataTbl D
GROUP BY 'Week ' + cast(WeekNumber as varchar(10))
```